# Gulp - saving different files to different paths not working as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gulp

Task:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'))
        .pipe(gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/*']))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/fonts'))
});
```

Expected output would be

```
- assets/css
    > bootstrap.min.css
- assets/fonts
    > glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    > glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    > glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    > glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    > glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

Instead what i get is

```
- assets/css
    > bootstrap.min.css
- assets/fonts
    > bootstrap.min.css
    > glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    > glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
```

Note that

- bootstrap css is copied to the fonts directory while it should not
- not all of the fonts were copied

What's wrong with my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant add sources like this. When you add .pipe(gulp.src) you are still working on the previous stream so your new src will be appended to the previous src. What you have to do is come out of the current stream.

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
         gulp.src([
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'))
        return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/fonts'))
});
```

Gulpjs reference

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md

Test script

```
gulp.task('copy:csstest', function() {
    gulp.src(['bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss']).pipe(gulp.dest("build/scripts/folder1"));
    return gulp.src(['bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*']).pipe(gulp.dest("build/scripts/folder2"));
});
```

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't solve because you are returning before setting up the fonts dst. However, your link does, merge-stream was the proper solution. Maybe edit your answer?

Comment: @brazorf are you sure? this versions pretty much solves the issue. I have attached my test script and the result. I am using gulp-3.9.0